# C++ Switch: case <some constant> - is this allowed?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, expression, constants, case

I am trying to do the following:

```
    switch(moveDirection){
        case MOVE_DIRECTION_UP:
            //do something
        break;
    }
```

Where MOVE_DIRECTION_UP is this:

```
    const unsigned char MOVE_DIRECTION_UP = 0x0;
```

The compiler gives the error: MOVE_DIRECTION_UP cannot appear in constant-expression

Surely this should be allowed, because it compiles fine if I replace MOVE_DIRECTION_UP with 0x0.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which compiler ? g++ does not give me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with C++11, you can declare `MOVE_DIRECTION_UP` as a `constexpr`. The compiler will regard it as a constant value that can be used as a switch label.

If you're not, you may define an enumeration:

```
namespace eDirection { enum e {
    UP = 0x0,
    DOWN = 0x1
};}

switch( direction ) {
    case eDirection::UP: ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is allowed in C++. Your code is correct. A `const` variable can be used in a constant expression.

Are you sure you're building a C++ source file and not C? In C, the code is not valid (a `const` variable *cannot* be used in a constant expression.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a compiler error.

In C++98:

> 5.19 Constant expression
>
> ...
>
> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals (2.13),
> enumerators, **const variables or static
> data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with
> constant expressions (8.5)**

In C++11:

> 5.19 Constant expressions
>
> ...
>
> 2 A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it
> involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>
> ...
>
> — an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
> — **a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile
> const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a
> constant expression**, or

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an actual program with your problem demonstrated, so I will use a crystal ball.  You forward declared your const and its value is not directly visible at the switch.